# kendoChart - Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function

Tags: error-handling, datasource, kendo-chart

I am getting this error message in console when using kendoChart :

> Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function

Here is my relevant JavaScript code:

```
    var stats = {
    occupation_sejour_long: [{
        value: 10,
        date: new Date("03/21/2016")
    }, {
        value: 20,
        date: new Date("03/28/2016")
    }, {
        value: 30,
        date: new Date("04/04/2016")
    }],
    occupation_sejour_court: [{
        value: 54,
        date: new Date("03/19/2016")
    }, {
        value: 63,
        date: new Date("03/25/2016")
    }, {
        value: 49,
        date: new Date("04/14/2016")
    }]
}
$("#chartOccupation").kendoChart({
    theme: "bootstrap",
    dataSource: {
        data: stats
    },
    title: {
        text: "Répartition Occupation / Type séjour ",
        position: "bottom",
    },
    legend: {
        visible: true,
        position: "bottom",
    },
    series: [{
            name: 'Séjour long',
            type: 'line',
            color: "blue",
            field: 'value',
            categoryField: 'date',
            data: stats.occupation_sejour_long
        },
        {
            name: 'Séjour court',
            type: 'line',
            color: "red",
            field: 'value',
            categoryField: 'date',
            data: stats.occupation_sejour_court
        }
    ],
    valueAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        majorUnit: 10,
        line: {
            visible: false,
        },
        labels: {
            format: "{0}%"
        },
    },
    categoryAxis: {
        labels: {
            dateFormats: {
                days: "dd/MM"
            }
        },
        baseUnitStep: 1,
        type: "date",
        justified: true,
        baseUnit: "days",
        rangeLabels: {
            dateFormats: {
                days: "dd/MM/yy"
            },
            visible: true
        },
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        template: "#= kendo.toString(dataItem.date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') # - #= dataItem.value #%",
    }
});
```

Although the chart output is displayed as expected, the error seems to affect some other parts of my code. For instance, This simple script doesn't work for me:

```
$("#dateDebut").change(function(e) {
            console.log("Testing....")
        });
```

Any explanations for that? What is wrong in my code and how should I fix it? Any idea?